# Coding standards for initializing views in android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the official coding standard for declaring and initializing views in Android using Kotlin? If it is case by case bases what cases would you use what?

I've seen these ways:

```
//Kotlin extensions
onCreate
...
btn_xml_tag.setOnClickListener {
        ...
} 

//More like java
private lateinit var button : Button 
...
onCreate
...
button = findViewById(R.id.button)
button?.setOnClickListener{...}

//Lazy
private val button : Button by lazy {
    findViewById(R.id.button_view) as Button
}
...
onCreate
...
button.setOnClickListener{...}
```

Comment: There is no official coding standard, it is up to you. My personal preference is Android XML Data Binding syntax: `binding.buttonView.setOnClickListener{...}`. I use it even if I don't use Data Binding itself, since I like the syntax so much.

Comment: You can use the synthetic version too , you dont need to use the findViewById(..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Android Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture). That is the standard way of doing it. As per the new architecture components, you don't need to access the instance of a view from code, but instead bind the data directly in the XML. The new architecture standard follows MVVM architecture.

With respect o your question, the best of the three options would be to use Kotlin Extensions, considering the readability and length of code. That is, the following would be the best approach(Though I would give the view an ID that would match with kotlin naming standards):

```
btnXmlTag.setOnClickListener {
        ...
}
```

Comment: If it would be the standard way of doing it, the Android team would surely use it in new sample code they write. But they don't, see e.g. https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L168

Comment: @Enselic Android architecture components are the new way of android development google has introduced. They have seperate samples for same. Google provides sample codes for distictive purposes, in case of the example provided, for getting a better idea for Camera APIs. Hence they use the old school methods for easier understanding of most of existing developers. Of course they have samples explicitly meant to demonstrate new architecture components. Like this repository: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples

Answer (score 0):

You can use android **DataBinding** and inflating those views directly in your Activity without intialization.

just you need to add these syntax in your gradle file.

> dataBinding{ enabled=true }

and in your layout file parent should be in **layout** tag